# Writing array contents to a file/Reading file contents into an array. Javascript/HTML5 Web Application

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, file, io

I am fairly new at Web Applications and I have a web application where the user can essentially create an array of objects based upon form input. I thought a very interesting feature would be if the web application had the ability for, upon the user clicking a "save" button, could download a formatted special file which would contain the contents of the array.

Along with this "save" feature, there would be a "load" feature which would load a specially formatted file which would first erase the contents of the existing array and fill the array with the contents described and parsed from the file loaded.

I have looked up some information regarding this process including information regarding HTML5's local storage feature, but it seems like the process of saving files to the client's computer from a browser application requires jumping through some loops to achieve due to security reasons.

Are there some workarounds to achieve this feature? Or would they seem to a bit too involved and complicated given the scale of application that this is.

Comment: `localStorage` could be perfect for you. Best thing is, there are no hoops to jump through or red tape to wade through to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping it simple first is the most efficient solution is to persist the values of input fields in localstorage key/value pairs instead of files. HTML5 localstorage is supported by the mainstream browsers.
You still have the cookies as an alternative option in case the localstorage isn't feasible.

You can find many tutorials to persist/read data to/from localstorage, [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-better-cookie-html5-and-web-storage/) is only one of them.

Comment: I agree, you should keep it as simple as possible. Files and parsing are overkill for this solution, HTML5 localstorage could be nice to combine the server-side with.

Comment: Would localstorage really be ideal for this? Essentially I'm wanting to save the array in it's entirety, to place this in perspective, imagine a online-shopper is adding some items(objects) to his cart(an array) and then wishes to save this cart. Then he starts anew, making a new cart(array) of items(objects), he decides that he prefers his previous cart or if he has saved several carts, he prefers one of his previous carts and he can select and upload that previous cart.

Comment: This kind of info (shopping cart item) are usually saved to a server-side database, because users can log in from a different machine. If you want to stick to the localstorage, the recommended data structure would look like the following: 
key: "cart_USERID", persisted value following JSON format: {[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6]}, where the firts array contains the content of the first cart and so on.